# Experiencing 'HTTP Error 400: Bad Request' on Google's Perspective API when passing a dataset in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, google-api, google-api-python-client

I've been trying to use Google's Perspective API to calculate Toxicity scores for tweet datasets, however, whenever I pass the dataframe, I keep getting the error 'HTTP Error 400: Bad Request'. Here is part of the code I have:

```
def scores(text):
    result = p.score(text, tests=["TOXICITY"])
    df.loc[index,'Toxicity']=result["TOXICITY"]
    
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    scores(row["text"])
    if index%10==0:
        time.sleep(10)
```

I've tried to use a few datasets each of 100 tweets. Only 1 successfully created the Toxicity scores column. What can be done?

Comment: Did you come up with solution?